# Resharper 6.1 Decompile Source option grey out (disabled)

Tags: resharper

I have the Resharper 6.1 Full Edition but my Decompile Sources option is grey out or not available in the Navigate To context menu... what should i do?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You should probably go to **ReSharper > Options > Tools > External Sources** and configure settings in this page the way that would allow decompiling - for example, select an option different than **Default Visual Studio navigation**

Comment: Mine was not grayed out, it was just not doing anything. This same fix resolved it for me.